# Unsorted Lists vs Linear and Binary Search

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

Hey guys so I've been studying for an upcoming test and I came across this question:

> If you had an unsorted list of one million unique items, and knew that you would only search it once for a value, which of the following algorithms would be the fastest?
>
> 1. Use linear search on the unsorted list
> 2. Use insertion sort to sort the list and then binary search on the sorted list

Wouldn't the second choice be the fastest? Sorting the list and then looking for the value than only using linear search?

Comment: It's unclear if the question implies sorting-and-searching the list every time you need to do the search or if it's implying sorting the list once and then only binary-searching it each subsequent time.

Comment: It also depends on the meaning of once-in-a-while and which value you are searching for

Comment: if you search a lot of times, sorting is better. It's even better to use a `set`

Comment: It's not a question for SO, I think. But linear seach is `O(n)` and best sorting gives you `O(nlogn)` and then `O(logn)` for binary search. So linear search will be faster. I think...

Comment: Well, what is the time complexity of the insertion sort?  That's your first step.

Comment: Just watch this before your test https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre op says `you would only search it once`

Comment: My fault, I misread that as "once in a while".

Comment: @Austin I'd interpret that as each item is itself unique and distinct from the other items, not every that item is the same value.

Comment: @TomDalton, I thought it all same at first. Got it late. That's why I deleted. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear search takes just *O(n)*, while sorting a list first takes *O(n log n)*. Since you are going to search the list only once for a value, the fact that subsequent searches in the sorted list with a binary search takes only *O(log n)* does not help overcome the overhead of the *O(n log n)* time complexity involved in the sorting, and hence a linear search would be more efficient for the task.

Answer (score 2):

sorting a list has a `O(log(N)*N)` complexity at best.

Linear search has `O(N)` complexity.

So if you have to search more than once, you begin to gain time after some searches.

If objects are hashable (ex: integers) a nice alternative (when searching more than once only) to sorting+bisection search is to put them in a `set`. Then complexity is down to `O(1)` because of hashing, but still `O(N)` to create it, and the hashing adds to the toll.

If you need only to search once, linear search is the best choice.

Comment: But adding them all to the set in the first place is still at least `O(n)`, and maybe `O(n log(n))` depending on the set implementation?

Comment: `set` uses hashes. Unlike C++ `map` which uses bisection (C++ hashmap are `unorderded_map` objects). So `O(1)` but `O(N)` at first of course, edited, was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative 1 of course, since that only requires you to go through the list once. If you are to sort the list, you have to traverse the list *at least* once for the sorting, and then some for the search.

Comment: How do you sort a list with `traverse the list at least once`?

Comment: @sashaaero: using bucket sort, each element must be visited at least once. Using a less efficient sorting algorithm will degrade performance further. Did that answer your question?

Comment: Bucket sort is `O(n^2)` this is not `once`. It `might` be linear, not guarantee. We always looking for worst case when analyzing algorithm.

Comment: @sashaaero You're allowed to traverse the list multiple times. The constraint is that you can only use one traversal for *searching for the value*

Comment: @sashaaero: you're doing it wrong. Even using best case scenario for sorting, it still will be slower. QED.

Comment: What am I "doing"? I don't get you.

Answer (score 1):

For solving these types of questions, it is simply necessary to see where you'd spend more time. For a million elements:

1. Insertion sort with 'n' inversions would take O(n) and then it would take an additional O(log(n)) time.
2. Whereas linear search would take only O(n) time.

Since there is only a single query method `1` would be a better alternative but for multiple queries(search element in the list) there will be a point where `bin-srch*x<lin-srch*x` where `x` is the  number of queries.

Comment: Insertion sort is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I've clearly mentioned "in the case of n inversions"

Comment: You should never depend on best case.